(WDI driver) how to deal with OID_WDI_SET_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION
I refer to MSDN docs and i learn the WDI sample. then i write my code.
You can see from the following logs, the first OidRequest is OID_WDI_GET_ADAPTER_CAPABILITIES, I handled the request correctly( i guess, otherwise i won't get the next OidRequest).
but i dont know how to handle the second OidRquest OID_WDI_GET_ADAPTER_CAPABILITIES.
DriverEntry: entry on Nov 11 2024 at 14:38:49
WDI_Initialize: entry
WDI_Initialize: WifiDeviceContext=FFFFF8042C971020, MiniportDriverHandle=FFFFBF892D43B2D0
WDI_Initialize: exit
DriverEntry: exit

EvtAllocateAdapter: entry
EvtAllocateAdapter: MiniportDriverContext=FFFFF8042C971020, MiniportDriverHandle=FFFFBF892D43B2D0, NdisMiniportHandle=FFFFBF892DBAB1A0
EvtAllocateAdapter: MiniportAdapterContext=pAdapter=FFFFF8042C971028
EvtAllocateAdapter: exit

EvtOpenAdapter: entry
EvtOpenAdapter: MiniportAdapterContext=FFFFF8042C971028, pAdapter=FFFFF8042C971028
EvtOpenAdapter: exit

EvtTalTxRxInitialize: entry
EvtTalTxRxInitialize: exit

EvtOidRequest: entry
EvtOidRequest: PropertyOid = OID_WDI_GET_ADAPTER_CAPABILITIES
OidHandle_GetAdapterCapabilities: entry
OidHandle_GetAdapterCapabilities: exit
EvtOidRequest: exit

EvtOidRequest: entry
EvtOidRequest: PropertyOid = OID_WDI_SET_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION
OidHandle_SetAdapterConfiguration: entry
OidHandle_SetAdapterConfiguration: exit
EvtOidRequest: exit

EvtTalTxRxDeinitialize: entry
EvtTalTxRxDeinitialize: free Nbl Pool successfully
EvtTalTxRxDeinitialize: exit

EvtCloseAdapter entry
EvtCloseAdapter: exit

EvtFreeAdapter: entry
EvtFreeAdapter: exit

EvtMiniportDriverUnload: entry
EvtMiniportDriverUnload: exit

I saw the WDI sample as follows:
NDIS_STATUS
WdiSimpleSetProperty(
    IN  PADAPTER            pAdapter,
    IN  PRSC_OID_HANDLER        pOidHandle
)
{
    PMGNT_INFO pMgntInfo = &(pAdapter->MgntInfo);
    PRSC_NDIS_COMMON pNdisCommon = pAdapter->pNdisCommon;

    PWDI_MESSAGE_HEADER pWdiHeader = (PWDI_MESSAGE_HEADER)pOidHandle->pNdisRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer;

    // We complete the OID. Need to populate some fields
    pWdiHeader->Status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    pOidHandle->pNdisRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesWritten = sizeof(WDI_MESSAGE_HEADER);

    switch (pOidHandle->pNdisRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.Oid)
    {
    case OID_WDI_SET_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION:
        N6InitializeNative80211MIBs(pAdapter);
        pMgntInfo->NdisVersion = MgntTranslateNdisVersionToRtNdisVersion(pNdisCommon->NdisVersion);
        break;
    }

    return NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

it just sets the pWdiHeader->Status and BytesWritten ( so do i ), function N6InitializeNative80211MIBs didn't nteract with the system, it just save some data in its custom struct.
so why i didn't get the third OidRequest? Who can help me? I would appreciate it!
If you think the previous steps were wrong, I can provide more information.
